# Can't delete reference many to many in ember/firebase

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I have a many to many relationship with this models in ember/firebase

```
model/video
export default Model.extend({
   ...
   tags: hasMany('tag', {async: true}),
   ...
});

model/tag

export default Model.extend({
  ...
  videos: hasMany('video', {async: true})
});
```

In controller have a delete action

```
delete(tag) {
  var videos = tag.get('videos');

  tag.destroyRecord().then(() =>{
    videos.map((video) => {
      video.save();
    });
  });
}
```

This action delete a tag record, but no in reference in video. When tag is delet videos var update to empty. 
How can i delete reference??

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the tag from your videos first, and then, you delete your tag.

```
tag.get('videos').forEach(function(video) {
    video.get('tags').removeObject(tag);
    video.save();
});

tag.destroyRecord();
```

Comment: your code works but if a tag have many videos don't delete all. Response in console is:
    tag.js:31Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Probably some of your old data that is in a "corrupt" state from your previous incomplete deletes. Can you try with 100% fresh data ?

Comment: Did you find your problem ?